# asp.net literal.text using multiple lines of html code

Tags: asp.net, string, html, literals

I am trying to initialize a literal with a big sequence of html code.
for example this is working just fine:

```
Literal1.Text.= "<ul><li>home<li/><ul/>";//just fine
```

But:
When i have more than one lines it doesn't work:

```
Literal1.Text.= "<ul><li>home
                 </li></ul>";//error
```

I know a simple solution which is this:

```
Literal1.Text.= "<ul><li>home"+
                "</li></ul>";//nice but time wasting for many lines
```

But:
When i have 100 lines for example i don't want to spend my time concatenating the strings.Is there any more practical solution?

Specifically my html code is the folowing:

```
    Literal1.Text.= "<ul id="nav">


<li class="current"><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com">People</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com">Customers</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/portfolio">View</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wp-themes">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wallpapers">Print</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/tutorials">Delete</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com">Employees</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/portfolio">View</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wp-themes">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wallpapers">Print</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/tutorials">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Quotations</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View</a></li>



    </ul>
</li>   


<li><a href="#">Invoices</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View</a></li>



    </ul>
</li>   

<li><a href="#">Receipts</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View</a></li>


    </ul>
</li>   

<li><a href="#">Statements</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>


    </ul>
</li>   

<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li class="style1"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>";
```

Comment: in addition to oded's answer you may have to replace `"` with `\"` [escape character] or `'` [single quotes will]

Comment: Althought Oded has the correct answer to your question, I can't help think that maybe you've made a design decision that should be rethought.  It *looks* like you are coming from the php world where you do a lot of html concatenation in code.. .Net takes a *different* approach.

Comment: @dchris I fixed your closing tags. Surely you meant `</foo>`, not `<foo/>`...

Comment: @rs:do i have to replace every single " with \";Because i tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small number of lines of code, I generally use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).  That way there are no performance issues with concatenating large immutable strings.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Add("<ul><li>home");
sb.Add("</li></ul>");
```

For a large number of lines, don't put them in your code at all.  Read them in using [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), so that you can edit your HTML without worrying about doubling your quotes.  If you're using the code a lot, read it in once using a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so that you're not causing a lot of extra IO usage.  Something like this (untested):

```
public static class HTMLStringClass
{
    private static string html;

    public static string GetHtmlString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            html = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file");
        return html;
    }
}
```

And then call it by doing this:

```
Literal1.Text = HtmlStringClass.GetHtmlString();
```

Comment: You could also use resource strings. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (one that starts with `@`):

```
Literal1.Text = @"<ul><li>home
                 </li></ul>";
```

Comment: Note that when using a double quotes inside a verbatim string literal, you escape them with another double quote "" instead of a backslash.

Comment: @Dave - Or, since this is an HTML literal, you can escape attributes using single quotes (`'`).